# Effective queries in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am reading an ML text that has a question:

> If we have a supervisor who can provide us with the label for any
>   **x**, where should we choose **x** to learn with fewer queries?

So I interpret this to mean:

> We are asked to help expedite the learning process by selecting test
>   elements that provide the most discriminatory information.

I would presume this would be an iterative algorithm: i.e. the selection of succeeding test elements depends upon what elements were previously selected. What is not clear from the question is:

- Would selection of succeeding elements *also* depend on the *results* of the prior queries.

So my question *here* would be: is there some information-theoretic unique answer to the above?  Or are there multiple approaches that may be of similar effectiveness/speed?

** *Footnote: this is not homework - it is my independent learning*

Comment: The book is "Introduction to Machine Learning", Ethem Alpaydin.

Comment: @paulsm4  Yes it is. Great text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches.
In fact, this setting is a machine learning task called [Active learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)). There are a lot of methods for choosing **x** based on different strategies - see section 3 of [this survey paper](http://burrsettles.com/pub/settles.activelearning.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In general, most techniques in Active learning (also known as Query learning or 'optimal experimental design') will use *all* observations, including the results or outcomes of previous enquiries. Since you wish to learn about the relationship between **x** and the outcome both pieces of information are useful for determining how to choose the optimal value of **x**.